# 401 Unauthorized https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken

Tags: azure, flask, powerbi, report, msal

I have an Rest API made in flask that is registered in Azure, My API allows logging in through Azure credentials, but when I go to generate an access token to access the powerbi reports through user's **access_token** logged in gives a status code **401**, specifically this error:

**Unauthorized**

**Error while retrieving Embed token Unauthorized:** {"error":{"code":"PowerBINotAuthorizedException","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBINotAuthorizedException","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

**Status Code**: 401

**RequestId:** d2d91052-9149-46e5-ba5b-551c18d82f09

I use the **msal** library.

In the API I have the following code:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, jsonify, redirect, url_for,flash,session,url_for, make_response, abort
from config import BROKER_URL, RESULT_BACKEND, SECRET_KEY, REDIRECT_PATH, CLIENT_ID, AUTHORITY, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_ID, ISSUER, SCOPE
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

@app.route('/login_microsft')
def login_microsoft():
    return redirect(AUTHORITY + "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
                    "response_type=code&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID +
                    "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_PATH +
                    "&scope=User.Read")

class EmbedTokenRequestBody:

    datasets = None
    reports = None
    targetWorkspaces = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.datasets = []
        self.reports = []
        self.targetWorkspaces = []

# autorización Microsoft
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():

    code = request.args.get('code')  # El código de autorización que Microsoft envía a esta URL
    if code:
        clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)
        token_response = clientapp.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code, SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)
        auth_result =token_response
        print('auth_result:',auth_result)

        group_id = "id_del_grupo"
        report_id = "id_del_informe"
        
        cabecera = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_result['access_token']}
        request_body = EmbedTokenRequestBody()

        request_body.reports.append({'id': report_id})
        request_body.targetWorkspaces.append({'id': group_id})

        embed_token_api = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken'
        api_response = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body.__dict__), headers=cabecera)

        if api_response.status_code != 200:
            abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed token\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nStatus Code:\t{api_response.status_code}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')
        

        # localiza el usuario en la base de datos
        usuarios= db['users']
        email = auth_result['id_token_claims']['preferred_username']
        user = usuarios.find_one({"email": email})
        if user:

            print("Usuario encontrado: " + str(user))  # imprimir usuario

            session['username'] = str(user["first_name"])
            session['position'] = str(user["position"])
            if(user['picture']):
                session['picture'] = user['picture']

            access_token = create_access_token(identity=str(user["_id"]))

            print('access_token:',access_token)

            response = make_response(redirect(url_for('home', _external=True)))

            # Establece las cookies de acceso
            response.set_cookie(
                'access_token',  # Nombre de la cookie
                value=access_token,  # Valor de la cookie, el token JWT
                httponly=True,  # Marcar la cookie como HTTP-Only
                secure=False,  # Marcar la cookie como segura (enviada solo a través de HTTPS)
                samesite='Lax'  # Política de SameSite permite que la cookie se envíe con solicitudes de navegación de nivel superior desde un origen externo
            )
            response.set_cookie(
                'access_token_ms',  # Nombre de la cookie
                value=auth_result['access_token'],  # Valor de la cookie
                httponly=True,  # Marcar la cookie como HTTP-Only
                secure=False,  # Marcar la cookie como segura (enviada solo a través de HTTPS)
                samesite='Lax'  # Política de SameSite permite que la cookie se envíe con solicitudes de navegación de nivel superior desde un origen externo
            )
            print('response:',response)
            print('status_code:',response.status_code)
            print('respuesta:',response.response)
            return response
        
    return 'Error: no se recibió el código de autorización'
```

Basically what it does is log in with Microsoft credentials and then generate access token for viewing PowerBi reports. In such a way that when you request the token from powerBI, that is, when you make a **request.pos** to https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken, you enter the **abort**.

I have the permissions that the API has in Azure:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeGnq.png)]

If anyone knows or can solve this problem for me, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using Microsoft Graph scope `User.Read` to get token and using it for Power BI API call that throws you 401 Unauthorized error. To resolve the error, change your scope to `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code flask  script is designed to facilitate the retrieval of an embed token for embedding Power BI reports
[image]
**Permission required :**

- **Content.Create**

  - **Permission Type**: Delegated
  - **Description**: Allows the user to create content within the Power BI Service.
  - **Granted for Contoso**: No
- **Dataset.Read.All**

  - **Permission Type**: Delegated
  - **Description**: Grants the ability to view all datasets.
  - **Granted for Contoso**: No
- **Report.Read.All**

  - **Permission Type**: Delegated
  - **Description**: Enables API calls requiring read permissions on all reports.
  - **Granted for Contoso**: No
- **Workspace.Read.All**

  - **Permission Type**: Delegated
  - **Description**: Provides the capability to view all workspaces.
  - **Granted for Contoso**: No

[image]

[image]

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

app = Flask(__name__)

CLIENT_ID =  'CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantiD'
REDIRECT_PATH = 'https://jwt.ms'  # Update with your redirect URI
SCOPE = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']

class EmbedTokenRequestBody:
    datasets = None
    reports = None
    targetWorkspaces = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.datasets = []
        self.reports = []
        self.targetWorkspaces = []

AUTHORIZE_URL = f'{AUTHORITY}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'

def get_authorization_url(client_id, redirect_uri, scope):
    return f'{AUTHORIZE_URL}?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={"%20".join(scope)}'

def get_access_token(authorization_code):
    clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)
    token_response = clientapp.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(authorization_code, scopes=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)
    return token_response.get('access_token')

def generate_embed_token(access_token, group_id, report_id):
    request_body = {
        "accessLevel": "View",
        "allowSaveAs": True
    }

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    embed_token_api = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports/{report_id}/GenerateToken'
    api_response = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body), headers=headers)

    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        error_data = api_response.json()
        error_code = error_data.get('error', {}).get('code', '')
        error_message = error_data.get('error', {}).get('message', api_response.reason)
        raise Exception(f"Error while retrieving Embed token: {error_message} (Error Code: {error_code})")

    try:
        embed_token = api_response.json().get('token')
        return embed_token
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        raise Exception("Error: Invalid JSON response received from the server")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    authorization_url = get_authorization_url(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_PATH, SCOPE)
    return f"<a href='{authorization_url}'>Click here to authenticate and get authorization code</a>"

@app.route('/auth_callback')
def auth_callback():
    authorization_code = request.args.get('code')
    access_token = get_access_token(authorization_code)
    if access_token:
        group_id = 'groupid'  # Replace with your group ID
        report_id = 'reportid'  # Replace with your report ID
        try:
            embed_token = generate_embed_token(access_token, group_id, report_id)
            print("\nAccess token:", access_token)  # Print access token to console
            print("Embed token:", embed_token)  # Print embed token to console
            return jsonify({"embed_token": embed_token})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)  # Print to console
            return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
    else:
        return "Error: No authorization code received", 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

[image]

```py
import json
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantiD'
REDIRECT_PATH = 'https://jwt.ms'  # Update with your redirect URI
SCOPE = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']

class EmbedTokenRequestBody:
    datasets = None
    reports = None
    targetWorkspaces = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.datasets = []
        self.reports = []
        self.targetWorkspaces = []

AUTHORIZE_URL = f'{AUTHORITY}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'

def get_authorization_url(client_id, redirect_uri, scope):
    return f'{AUTHORIZE_URL}?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={"%20".join(scope)}'

def get_access_token(authorization_code):
    clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)
    token_response = clientapp.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(authorization_code, scopes=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)
    return token_response.get('access_token')

def generate_embed_token(access_token, group_id, report_id):
    request_body = {
        "accessLevel": "View",
        "allowSaveAs": True
    }

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    embed_token_api = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports/{report_id}/GenerateToken'
    api_response = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body), headers=headers)

    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        error_data = api_response.json()
        error_code = error_data.get('error', {}).get('code', '')
        error_message = error_data.get('error', {}).get('message', api_response.reason)
        raise Exception(f"Error while retrieving Embed token: {error_message} (Error Code: {error_code})")

    try:
        embed_token = api_response.json().get('token')
        return embed_token
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        raise Exception("Error: Invalid JSON response received from the server")

# Example usage:
authorization_url = get_authorization_url(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_PATH, SCOPE)
print("Authorization URL:", authorization_url)

authorization_code = input("Enter authorization code: ")
access_token = get_access_token(authorization_code)
if access_token:
    print("\nAccess token:", access_token)
    
    group_id = 'groupid'  # Replace with your group ID
    report_id = 'reportid'  # Replace with your report ID
    
    try:
        embed_token = generate_embed_token(access_token, group_id, report_id)
        print("\nEmbed token:", embed_token)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
else:
    print("Error: No authorization code received")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem, it was that the permissions of a Powerbi workspace user had to be changed for the changes to be applied and the API in Powerbi to have access.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).